# Will storing geospatial data in a database improve performance of R

Tags: postgresql, r

When working with `sp` objects in R (large `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to be exact) I run into performance issues (mostly memory related - e.g. `save_tmap()` from `tmap` package fails).

Will the performance improve if I store the polygons in a database, e.g. Postgres, instead of regular R objects? I have the `rgdal` and `rgeos` packages, but no experience with PostGIS.

Comment: Is `LargeSpatialPolygonsDataFrame` a thing or do you mean "large `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`"?

Comment: It is not; I meant the "standard" `sp` object. I have edited the question to make myself clear. Thanks!

Comment: The sf (simple features) package is supposed to be an improved and faster sp. https://www.r-consortium.org/blog/2017/01/03/simple-features-now-on-cran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Its unlikely you'll get better memory performance unless you are working with subsets of large objects.

For example, R has to read all of a shapefile into memory, even if all you want to do is plot a selection of the shapes. But you could have a huge spatial database on a PostGIS server and load only the bits you want via SQL.

But `save_tmap()` will do the same thing no matter where the data is being stored.

Comment: That is bad news, but I appreciate it anyway :) I was being lazy, and trying to work with administrative units at the lowest level of detail (instead of creating several different intermediate aggregate shapefiles).